# How to change warning text when pattern is used in input?

Tags: html

When I use pattern in input like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern="(\d|(\d,\d{0,2}))">
```

I receive popup warning with text. How can I easily change this text?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern="(\d|(\d,\d{0,2}))" title="YOUR_WARNING_TEXT" >
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern="(\d|(\d,\d{0,2}))" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ERROR_TEXT')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

Try this code, corrected to clear after input...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I like that this replaces the default warning instead of appending to it

Comment: Make sure to also add oninput to clear the setCustomValidity, otherwise the user will be stuck when they attempt to fix the error

Answer (score 7):

The text shown can be defined in the `title` attribute of the `input` tag.

Comment: Title added to end of default warning. any way to totaly overwrite it?

Comment: Is there any reason you chose the other answer over this one even though it was answered first with the same information? I know it was a long time ago. Just curious

Answer (score 5):

The `title` is appended to the pattern warning. Just keep in mind the warnings are translated into the browser language, which can make an english string look odd.

This is the only way I found to completely replace the warning:

```html
<input type="text" required pattern="PATTERN" oninvalid="invalid" oninput="invalid">
```

```
/**
 * Shows a custom validity message
 * @param e - event
 */
function invalid(e) {
  if (!/PATTERN/.test(e.target.value)) { // somehow validity.valid returns a wrong value
    e.target.setCustomValidity('INVALID')
  } else {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('')
  }
}
```

Once the form is validated, the warning keeps popping up until the value matches the pattern. If the `input` event is just setting `setCustomValidity('')` as suggested in most other answers, the default warning returns.