# How can I customize the 2 attributes of the Input Field?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, attributes

### How can I customize the 2 warning text in 1 Input Field.

> The **1 is for required**/invalid and The **1 is for pattern** *(2 attributes for validation)*.

I try to do it, **Somebody, Please Help Me**, **Correct the Code**, **The  Codepen link** is on the **comment section**.

---

**I search this including on the stackoverflow** but I can't find any solution for this answer.

*Cuz'* **The only thing they asked & already answered was the 1 warning txt customization only**.

*Like this one: [changing the language of error message in required field in html5 contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form)*

*& this one: [How to change warning text when pattern is used in input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739079/how-to-change-warning-text-when-pattern-is-used-in-input)*

---

> I'm beginner in js, **I only know some basics** & **I'm trying to find some clues on how can I do it, But i can't find any answer.** *Thankyou so much in advance for your help.*

---

Comment: Look at the JSFiddle link in the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753881/changing-the-language-of-error-message-in-required-field-in-html5-contact-form -- Where it tests `if (!textfield.validity.valid)`, instead test for `if (textfield.validity.valueMissing)` and set a message to indicate the field is required, `elseif (textfield.validity.patternMismatch)` and set a message to indicate a pattern failure.

Comment: You can look at bootstrap validation from here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner in js I only know some basics, How to do it, this is what i do: https://codepen.io/supreme-07/pen/yLbPRdy

Original Fiddle that you said: http://jsfiddle.net/zpkKv/2/